# Split an array with range conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have an array like following:

```
    sortedransam={{0.105328, -0.0291632}, {0.253571, 0.00498561}, {0.410887, 
  0.171317}, {1.45579, 0.300952}, {2.56002, -0.0599007}, {3.67651, 
  0.0913857}, {4.44773, -0.21599}, {4.68098, 0.0766649}, {5.20004, 
  0.0153934}, {5.31011, 0.157674}, {6.25626, -0.119345}, {6.35928, 
  0.145992}, {6.52711, -0.0163245}, {7.44436, 0.0334628}, {7.8401, 
  0.305493}, {8.18541, 0.0712892}, {8.21423, -0.0325363}, {9.0921, -0.0242404}, {9.3285, 0.035512}}
```

`sortedransam`'s first colume has been sorted. I would like to split this array with conditions that the first column into range ex. 0-2, 2-4, 4-6...
Then the `sortedransam` should be like

```
    {{{0.105328, -0.0291632}, {0.253571, 0.00498561}, {0.410887, 
  0.171317}, {1.45579, 0.300952}},
  {{2.56002, -0.0599007}, {3.67651, 0.0913857}},
  {{4.44773, -0.21599}, {4.68098, 0.0766649}, {5.20004, 0.0153934}, {5.31011, 0.157674}},
  {{6.25626, -0.119345}, {6.35928, 0.145992}, {6.52711, -0.0163245}, {7.44436, 0.0334628}, 
  {7.8401,0.305493}},
  {{8.18541, 0.0712892}, {8.21423, -0.0325363}, {9.0921, -0.0242404}, {9.3285, 0.035512}}}
```

Should I use `SplitBy` or something else? I don't know how to get conditions implemented.

Answer (score 5):

```
SplitBy[sortedransam, Quotient[First[#], 2] &]
```

> ```
>  {{{0.105328, -0.0291632}, {0.253571, 0.00498561}, {0.410887, 0.171317}, {1.45579, 0.300952}},
>  {{2.56002, -0.0599007}, {3.67651, 0.0913857}}, 
>  {{4.44773, -0.21599}, {4.68098, 0.0766649}, {5.20004, 0.0153934}, {5.31011, 0.157674}}, 
>  {{6.25626, -0.119345}, {6.35928, 0.145992}, {6.52711, -0.0163245}, 
>   {7.44436, 0.0334628}, {7.8401, 0.305493}},
>  {{8.18541, 0.0712892}, {8.21423, -0.0325363}, {9.0921, -0.0242404}, {9.3285, 0.035512}}}
> ```

You can also use [`BinLists`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinLists.html):

```
Join @@ BinLists[sortedransam, {0, 10, 2}, {-1, 1, 2}]
```

> same result

Answer (score 4):

Not too hard with `GatherBy[]` + `Floor[]`:

```
GatherBy[sortedransam, Floor[First[#], 2] &]
   {{{0.105328, -0.0291632}, {0.253571, 0.00498561}, {0.410887, 0.171317},
     {1.45579, 0.300952}},
    {{2.56002, -0.0599007}, {3.67651, 0.0913857}},
    {{4.44773, -0.21599}, {4.68098, 0.0766649}, {5.20004, 0.0153934},
     {5.31011, 0.157674}},
    {{6.25626, -0.119345}, {6.35928, 0.145992}, {6.52711, -0.0163245},
     {7.44436, 0.0334628}, {7.8401, 0.305493}},
    {{8.18541, 0.0712892}, {8.21423, -0.0325363}, {9.0921, -0.0242404},
     {9.3285, 0.035512}}}
```